# SQL query which reformats results

Tags: sql, select, db2

Here is the example 'sales' table of data
[image]

Here is the desired output Result Set
[image]

---

Here is an example of the **undesired** Result Set that would be generated from this SQL statement.

```
SELECT Vendor, SUM(Markdown), SUM(Regular), SUM(Promotion), SUM(Returned)
FROM sales
GROUP BY Vendor, Date
```

[image]

---

Is there a way to get the desired result set through just SQL?

We are running a SQL DB2 database on an IBM iSeries.

I do realize this is a very odd way to try to do this... we are just trying to find a way to get the result set back as needed, without having to do any manual conversion of the results through code.

Comment: What DMBS are you using? Does it support `UNPIVOT`?

Comment: We are using a SQL DB2 Database run on an IBM I. *Added to OP*

Comment: @Adam Should the results be grouped by date? If so, wouldn't it be better to include the date in the output? Otherwise you won't be able to determin what date a total is for

Comment: No, date should not be part of the results.  The results should be a SUM of all dates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to use `UNION` statement

try,

```
SELECT Vendor, 'Markdown' as Type,  SUM(Markdown) as Amount 
FROM sales 
GROUP BY Vendor, Date

UNION

SELECT Vendor, 'Regular' as Type, SUM(Regular) as Amount  
FROM sales 
GROUP BY Vendor, Date

UNION

SELECT Vendor, 'Promotion' as Type, SUM(Promotion) as Amount 
FROM sales 
GROUP BY Vendor, Date

UNION

SELECT Vendor, 'Returned' as Type, SUM(Returned) as Amount 
FROM sales 
GROUP BY Vendor, Date
```

Comment: I think you should remove "Date" from your group by

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I don't see why a join should be needed here, I think the query in this answer will produce the result that the OP asked for

Comment: @thaJeztah Yep, you don't need the Date

Comment: +1  This looks right to me... not sure about the grouping on `Date`... OP included it in his sample group by, and the totals in the desired data indicate a grouping by on date as well...

Comment: @John I re-checked the desired output as asked by the OP, and Date should be in the group-by after all, however, by not including if in the field-list of the select may produce unwanted effects, because duplicate rows (e.g. Non-unique rows) may be returned? I'd suggest adding a 'date' column in the output?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson we all make mistakes sometimes :)

Comment: +1 and a tiny little note: `union` has to `distinct` all rows, while `union all` does not. As all the rows are clearly different, `union all` wins.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you everyone.  Although having date in the Group By seems to produce the same results as not having date. Side Note - - - should I retitle this post so the subject has 'Union' in it??